# Partially sorting an array C

Tags: c, arrays, qsort

I have an array which looks like this:

```
int array[] = {4.53, 3.65, 7.43, 9.54, 0.72, 0.0}
```

I am just wondering what method I can use to partially sort this array to bring the top three biggest doubles to the front. I am looking for the most efficient method to get the top three highest numbers in this array.

So far I have been using `qsort`, but I am just looking for another method to do this which could be even faster. I know that `qsort` is `O(nlogn)` for best cases and `O(n^2)` for worst cases, but is there an even more efficient method to achieve this problem? What I mean by efficient is just a faster way to do it, better than `O(nlogn)`.

Any help would be great

Comment: How would you find just the smallest number? Do that with three variables.

Comment: Would that be more efficient than `qsort`?

Comment: @RoadRunner finding the most extreme value in an array is O(n) and finding the `k` most extreme values in an array is O(kn) and assuming `k<n` it is indeed faster.

Comment: The method  is usually called quick-select. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: Quickselect gives an average of O(n) regardless of k.  However, in this case, because k is 3 Nikhil's method may be quickest.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: It can be done more quickly than that actually. Creating a heap from an array can be done in a single `O(n)` step, and popping off `k` values from it costs `O(log n)` per item. So you can make the cost `O(max(n, k log n))` (which means if `k == n`, you just paid roughly the expected `O(n log n)` cost of a full sort, where doing `k` linear scans would scale to `O(n**2)`). I assume stuff like [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) uses an algorithm of this sort to avoid poor scaling when `k` is an appreciable percentage of `n`.

Comment: On second thought, @EdwardJezisek suggestion to quickselect for `k`, then sort only the values on one side of the resulting partition, which achieves `O(max(n, k log k))` performance, is probably what `partial_sort` really uses. Oops.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions? Could these methods be done with sorting an array of structs?

Comment: Quick select can.  I assume that partial sort would take in a comparator which would do what you need.  But, if you only need the top 3 elements it will likely be quicker to use the method proposed by Nikhil as the big O constant will be lower (3) versus I think about 11 or so for quickselect(This is likely off, do not quote me)

Per wikipedia:
Finer computations of the average time complexity yield a worst case of 3.4n+o(n) which is slightly larger than 3n.

Comment: Is partial_sort available in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply maintain first, second, third.

```
   first =  array[0];
   second = array[1];
   third = array[2];

   /* scratch sort for three elements */
   if(first < second)
     swap(first, second);
  if(first < third)
     swap(first, third);
  if(second < third)
     swap(second, third);

  /* now go through, bubbling up if we have a hit */ 
  for(i=3;i<N;i++)
  {
      if(third < array[i])
      {
         third = array[i];
         if(second < third)
         {
            swap(second, third);
            if(first < second)
              swap(first, second);
         }
      }
  }
```

I wouldn't try to scale up to k = four. I think three is about the limit for hardcoding it. As k get large you need to move to a formal method.

This doesn't answer the question you actually asked, which was how to partially sort, but it seems to be what you want.

If you wish to partially sort, you can use quicksort, and simply return early when the pivot goes above the bound you are interested it. So our first pivot divides into five, two. Ignore the last two, and only actually do the sub-sorts of the last five. But whilst it will be faster than quicksort, it won't be a game changer. If you can get a conservative upper bound on the k'th item (eg it's always going to be at most 25% between the minimum and the mean) you can quickly eliminate most of the data. If you get it wrong it's just another pass or two.

Using the quicksort method

```
  int sortfirstk_r(int *array, int N, int k)
  {
     int pivot = 0;
     int j = n -1;
     int i = 1;

     while(i <= j)
     {
        if(array[pivot] < array[i])
          swap(array[i], array[j--])
        else
          i++;

     }
     sortfirstk_r(array, i, k < i ? k : i);
     if(i < k)
       sortfirstk_r(array +i, N -i, k - i); 

  }
```

(Untested and there might be bugs in the slightly tricky sort logic).

However we've naively used the first element as the pivot. If we're sorting a large data set, and it has a normal distribution, and we want the top 1%, the z-score is 2.326. Take a bit more to allow us some sampling error, and we make a first pass with a pivot set at say 2.3 standard deviations above the mean. Then we split the distribution into two sets, the top 1% plus a bit, and the rest. We don't need to further process the rest, and just sort the top group.

Answer (score 3):

For your specific problem the quickest method is to do something similar to below since you only want three elements: (It may be quicker to use a priority queue or a different data structure, but the speed will not be very noticeable)

```
#include"stdio.h"
void moveThreeMaxToFront(double * arr, int length);
void moveMaxToFront(double*arr, int length);
int main() {
  int i;
  double meh[]={ 5,3,1,7,2,9,11};
  moveThreeMaxToFront(meh, 7);
  for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    printf("%f \n", meh[i]);
}
void moveThreeMaxToFront(double * arr, int length) {
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    moveMaxToFront(arr++, length-i);
}
void moveMaxToFront(double* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for(i=1; i<length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]>arr[0]) {
      double tmp=arr[i];
      arr[i]=arr[0];
      arr[0]=tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

However, it is potentially faster if k becomes substantially larger to either implement [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) or use the partial_sort method which I believe implements quickselect.  However, the quickselect algorithm for the given case has an average constant of approximately 3.4-4.4 which is slightly larger than the constant above(3).  Please also note that quickselect has an average run time of O(n).  This run time can be guaranteed using median of 3, but this is not advised as it significantly increases the average constant.  Intro-select properly handles this to prevent the worst case of quickselect while retaining its average case.

Answer (score 0):

If we are supposed to find out the three largest number then we can run `findMax` method three times and once a maximum is found replace appropriate index `(1, 2 or 3)` with maximum in array. This way we leave you with array will `3` largest elements at start of array in `c * O(n)` time-complexity.

**Note:** I used fact that you have to find first three maximum doubles

```
double findMax(double arr[i], double prevMax){
    double maximum = -100000000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] < prevMax)
        maximum = max(arr[i], maximum);
    }
    return maximum;
 }
```

Comment: With an array such as `{-10, -9, -8, -7}`, replacing with -1 would not produce the correct result. We don't know if we can assume that numbers are all positive.

Comment: There is no `Math.max` in C. Also: use `isgreater()` or one of the other functions offered in `>=C99` for comparing floating point values.

Comment: @NikhilPathania `max()` does not work for all floating point values, its name clashes with the variable `max` in `findMax` and `float.h` has the necessary macros to find the smallest value a `double` can represent, please use it.

Comment: Why is `double[]` the returned type if you are returning just a number?

Comment: Some errors might be there, just a basic idea of implementation

Comment: Your fix is *"-100000000000 should be enough"*, but there are other ways to solve the problem correctly for all cases.

Comment: @NikhilPathania Is it so much work to include `float.h` and set the start-value of `maximum` to `-DBL_MAX`? Also `mmax()` is still wrong. You can use the function `isgreater()` (assumes `>=c99`) for comparing two floats or check for `NaN` and the other exceptions manually.

Comment: I dont know much about C, i generally code in java, you can provide me with edits @deamentiaemundi

Comment: @NikhilPathania if you don't know how to code in C than why do put C-code in your answer?

Comment: Answer was to suggest an idea @deamentiaemundi

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest radix sort it is the most efficient sorting method for such cases and has complexity O(n). You could even change it alittle bit to stop when find three max numbers.
You can find-understand radix short:
https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RadixSort.html

Comment: There is one problem that in radix-sort your space-complexity comes into play and therefore it will work for values less than `10^7`

Comment: Why 10^7 ,you say that we can't have arrays bigger than 10^7??

Comment: Maximum value of any number in array can be `10^7` to do radix sort

Comment: I may agree with the a0^7 for any number though I've never read that anywhere, but then your previous posts don't make sense because n is the length of array and not of any element.