# Sorting an array of structs Efficiently

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I am sorting an array of structs using `qsort`, and I am looking for a more efficient way to extract the top three highest scores by partially sorting the array. My structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    double score;
    int player_num;
} player_t;
```

and I have malloced an array of structures like this:

```
player_t *players = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(player_t));
```

The way I sort this array of structures is by first sorting the scores, and if the scores have ties, then sort by the player number.

My code looks like this with `qsort`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 6
#define MAX 3

int scorecmp(const void *a, const void *b);
int ComparePlayerScore( const void* ap , const void* bp );
int CompareInt( const int a , const int b );

typedef struct {
    double score;
    int player_num;
} player_t;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    int player_numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    double scores[] = {0.765, 0.454, 0.454, 0.345, 0.643, 0.532};

    player_t *players = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(player_t));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        players[i].score = scores[i];
        players[i].player_num = player_numbers[i];
    }

    qsort(players, SIZE, sizeof(*players), ComparePlayerScore);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Player %d: Score: %.3f\n", players[i].player_num, players[i].score);
    }

    free(players);

    return 0;
}

int ComparePlayerScore( const void* ap , const void* bp ) {
    const player_t* const a = ap;
    const player_t* const b = bp;

    if( a->score == b->score ){
        return CompareInt( a->player_num , b->player_num );
    }
    else if( a->score > b->score ) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int CompareInt( const int a , const int b ) {
    if( a < b ){
        return -1;
    }
    else if( a > b ){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am just looking for another way to do this, but a more efficient way to extract the top 3 the scores, along with the respective player numbers. Like a way where I can extract the top three elements of the array without having to sort the whole array first everytime.

Comment: I guess this a follow-up to a [recently answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061974/partially-sorting-an-array-c).

Comment: Yeah, I have been experimenting with this, and trying to make it work with `qsort` but I can't seem to do this without sorting the whole array first. It seems like using an array of structures is making it more difficult.

Comment: I'd say don't worry about performance at this level. Your array has only size 6, so it is not worth optimizing away the three comparisons that might be redundant. Keep your code simple. And, if you later have _measured_ that this part of the program is by far the slowest, only then should you optimize it.

Comment: Do you need to (partially) sort the array, or just find the index values of the 3 elements with the highest scores?

Comment: Yeah, it's just that, I am curious about the performance when the array gets really big. But I am not sure how to optimize it theoretically for that.

Comment: Yeah I want to just be able to find the top three scores, with their respective player numbers. Not so fussy about partially sorting array.@WeatherVane

Comment: Just keep a separate list of the three top scores, updating it when you add to the larger array.

Comment: I added a solution implementing my idea below.

Comment: I wonder if you would consider changing the title of this question to something like, "Extracting extremal values from an array of structs," since you aren't really interested in sorting the whole array? I believe that all of the solutions below address this different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple try, see online demonstration on http://ideone.com/8A1lnP.

```
struct top3_players {
  player_t *top[3];
};

void top3_determine(struct top3_players *top, player_t *players, size_t n) {
  player_t *top1 = NULL;
  player_t *top2 = NULL;
  player_t *top3 = NULL;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    player_t *player = &players[i];
    if (top1 == NULL || ComparePlayerScore(player, top1) < 0) {
      top3 = top2;
      top2 = top1;
      top1 = player;
    } else if (top2 == NULL || ComparePlayerScore(player, top2) < 0) {
      top3 = top2;
      top2 = player;
    } else if (top3 == NULL || ComparePlayerScore(player, top3) < 0) {
      top3 = player;
    }
  }
  top->top[0] = top1;
  top->top[1] = top2;
  top->top[2] = top3;
}
```

Comment: Is the dummy comparator educational in some way?

Comment: No, it was just to make my code compilable on its own when I pasted it into ideone. I deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

This is my offering. Since you have `#define MAX` for how many top scores you want to find, I have considered that.

The program makes a single pass of the data, and 1 pass of the topmost for each of the records. I have used a fixed array, you'll have to adapt to your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 6
#define MAX 3

typedef struct {
    double score;
    int player_num;
} player_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    player_t players[SIZE] = {{2.0, 2}, {4.0, 5}, {1.0, 4}, {1.0, 1}, {5.0, 3}, {4.0, 6}};
    int order[MAX+1] = {0};
    int found = 1;
    int i, j;
    int bigger;

    for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        bigger = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < found; j++) {
            if(players[i].score > players[ order[j] ].score) {
                bigger = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if(players[i].score == players[ order[j] ].score && 
                    players[i].player_num < players[ order[j] ].player_num) {
                bigger = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(bigger) {
            memmove(order + j + 1, order + j, (found - j) * sizeof order[0]);
            order[j] = i;
            if(found < MAX) {
                found++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < found; i++) {
        printf("%d %f\n", players[ order[i] ].player_num, players[ order[i] ].score); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
3 5.000000
5 4.000000
6 4.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that keeps track of the top three scores by storing pointers to them. When you add a player or change a score, an update function is called to keep the top-score list current. The advantage here is that you only ever need to iterate over a list of three elements. I modified your original code to demonstrate how this might work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 6
#define MAX 3

typedef struct {
    double score;
    int player_num;
} player_t;

void update_topscores(player_t **top, player_t *pplayer);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    int player_numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    double scores[] = {0.765, 0.454, 0.454, 0.345, 0.643, 0.532};

    player_t *players = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(player_t));
    player_t **topscores = calloc(3, sizeof(player_t *));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        players[i].score = scores[i];
        players[i].player_num = player_numbers[i];
        update_topscores(topscores, &(players[i]));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Player %d: Score: %.3f\n",
               players[i].player_num, players[i].score);
    }

    puts("Top Scores");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Player %d: Score: %.3f\n",
               topscores[i]->player_num, topscores[i]->score);    
    }

    /* Change score for player 4 */
    players[3].score = 0.755;
    update_topscores(topscores, &(players[3]));
    puts("New Top Scores");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Player %d: Score: %.3f\n",
               topscores[i]->player_num, topscores[i]->score);
    }

    free(players);
    free(topscores);

    return 0;
}

void update_topscores(player_t **top, player_t *pplayer)
{
    int i;
    player_t *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if (top[i] == NULL) {
            top[i] = pplayer;
            return ;
        }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ((pplayer->score) > (top[i]->score)) {
            temp = top[i];
            top[i] = pplayer;
            update_topscores(top, temp);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ;
}
```

You can see that there is a function `update_topscores()` that is used to update the list. In the above code, this is used when building the initial list of players. Then, when the score of Player 4 is updated, the function is called again, resulting in a new list of top scores. The list is not sorted, but it would be easy to do so if desired, and you would only be sorting a list of three entries.

There was an additional allocation for three pointers to player pointers, `topscores`, which must of course be freed at the end.

Here is a sample output:

```
Player 1: Score: 0.765
Player 2: Score: 0.454
Player 3: Score: 0.454
Player 4: Score: 0.345
Player 5: Score: 0.643
Player 6: Score: 0.532
Top Scores
Player 1: Score: 0.765
Player 5: Score: 0.643
Player 6: Score: 0.532
New Top Scores
Player 1: Score: 0.765
Player 4: Score: 0.755
Player 5: Score: 0.643
```